# Android: Get textColor attribute from a certain style defined in styles.xml

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two styles defined in `styles.xml` and `styles.xml(v21)`. They both include a `textAppearance` attribute that links to a certain default android text style.

**styles.xml**

```xml
<style name="NotificationTitle">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">
        @android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title
    </item>
</style>
```

**styles.xml (v21)**

```xml
<style name="NotificationTitle">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">
        @android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title
    </item>
</style>
```

These default styles contain some text attributes: `textColor`, `textSize`, etc:

```xml
...
<style name="TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title">
    <item name="textColor">@color/primary_text_default_material_light</item>
    <item name="textSize">@dimen/notification_title_text_size</item>
</style>
...
```

I need to get this `textColor` programmatically by the name of my custom style (NotificationTitle in the example). I tried to obtain it using `obtainStyledAttributes`, but it don't return. What should I do?

```java
int resultColor;
int[] attrs = {android.R.attr.textColor};
TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.NotificationText, attrs);

if (ta != null) {
    resultColor = ta.getColor(0, Color.TRANSPARENT);
    ta.recycle();
}
```

Comment: make sure you are passing the right context.

Comment: The context is appropriate, I just checked - if I pass directly. `android.R.style.TextAppearance_Material_Notification_Title` into `obtainStyledAttributes ` it will return the right color. But if I pass my custom style `R.style.NotificationText` it won't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if I'm a bit late with an answer but I tried your code with a bit of modification, I changed the style to this:

```
<style name="NotificationTitle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Title"/>
<style name="NotificationText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Line2"/>
```

and everything worked well with the rest of your code (and didn't need the v21 for the styles now that I used AppCompat)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried that old example with the changes you have proposed — and it works! For some reason, I didn't try to inherit my custom styles directly from `TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title` and `TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title`. Finally, the question is closed.

Comment: Glad I could help